# Using an .ovpn file to set up a VPN on Antergos Gnome

Tags: linux, gnome, openvpn, vpn, antergos

I downloaded my VPN configuration files from my provider which had updated the files a while back. Before this update, the VPN connection setup process had been flawless but now that I try to create a new connection in NetworkManager, connection won't be established.

Here is a simple form of an example config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn_ip vpn_port
resolv-retry infinite
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Server Authentication"
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
THE CERTIFICATE
</ca>
<tls-auth>
OPENVPN STATIC KEY
</tls-auth>
key-direction 1
```

Comment: look at logs, ask your provider